# php mongodb findOne return as object?

Tags: php, mongodb

is it possible to return findOne result as object ..or it always return an array?

i found something about mongo.objects = 1 adding to php.ini   ..but did not work for me.

can some one tell me more about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no mentioning of the MongoDB PHP driver returning objects in either the API documentation or the tutorial. This is not really surprising as the official drivers stay close to the native bson document type used to represent documents.

There are however plenty of extra libraries that provide such mapping. Looking at the [PHP Language Center page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center) at mongodb.org, for example, I see a few libraries that provide direct object mapping, such as simplemongodb or mongodb-php-odm.
They use their own API, so maybe just writing a simple conversion function from an array to an object instance yourself is more suited for you.

Comment: That was kind of dumb on their part. JSON/BSON is object-based, so why are they returning arrays? Sounds like the PHP library is wasting time trying to make it more php friendly.